# Показывать статус билда (сборки) на Jenkins в репозитории на гитлабе

Tags: gitlab, jenkins

Пытаюсь реализовать статус билда в репозитории на гитлабе.
В readme.md добавляю

```
[![build status](http://mygitlab.ru/root/My_Repository/badges/master/build.svg)](http://myjenkins.ru/job/My_Jenkins_Repository/)
```

Статус сборки после git push отображается как unknown, но сама сборка в jenkins проходит успешно.

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сборка на Jenkins происходит? Тогда GitLab ничего не знает о статусе сборки (потому и статус unknown).

Картинку нужно получать из Jenkins. Вроде бы задачу решает плагин [Embeddable Build Status](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin). В примере ниже я переделал ссылки `[](url)` в `[][label] [label]:url` для большей читаемости:

```
[![build status][badge]][jenkins]

[badge]: https://myjenkins.ru/job/My_Jenkins_Repository/badge/icon
[jenkins]: http://myjenkins.ru/job/My_Jenkins_Repository/
```

Если у вас GitLab EE, то лучше [настроить интеграцию с Jenkins](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html), тогда GitLab будет показывать статус сборки «нативным» образом — как для сборок на GitLab CI.